# camelContext attribute discriminator for tenant resolver , using jpa multitenant and camel routeId

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-data-jpa

i ask you how can use camelContext to get the name of route fired by an event, more in details, how can I use any kind of discriminator attribute x in camelContext for predicate decision (if  x =1 then .. else ..)
For example:

I have this kind of route:

```
//this route use the forst database
    from("direct:csvprocessor1")
        .routeId("tenant1")
        .from("file:src/main/resources/data/1?move=OUT&moveFailed=REFUSED")
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData")
        .setBody(constant("OK VB"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/html"));
```

and this other route:

```
//this route use tenant2, the second database
    from("direct:csvprocessor1")
        .routeId("tenant2")
        .from("file:src/main/resources/data/2?move=OUT&moveFailed=REFUSED")
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData")
        .setBody(constant("OK 2"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/html"));
```

when i pick up file in 1 folder the first route named "tenant1" starts, the same happen when pick up file in 2, the second route tenant2 starts.It reads csv content and the content must be write using jpa on the right tenantX (database)

I have to retrieve routeid name in another class but this class instanced before the camel Context start so i can't inject context (because this class "BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl " belong to Spring database initializator). I try to add method "of" to set camelContext but i get tenant1 only, also when route 2 starts, so can't switch from tenant to another tenant (tenant is database, i have two database):

```
@Component
public class BatchTenantContext {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchTenantContext.class);

    // don't Inject, use method Of because injecton was null
    CamelContext cctx;

    public BatchTenantContext(){getInstance();}

    private final static BatchTenantContext instance = new BatchTenantContext();

    public static BatchTenantContext getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized String get() {
        if (cctx != null){
            Route val = cctx.getRoute("tenant1");
            if (val == null){
                val = cctx.getRoute("tenant2");
                if (val == null){
                    return "";
                }
                else {
                    return "tenant_2";
                }
            }
            else return "tenant_1";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public synchronized void of(CamelContext ctx){
        cctx = ctx;
    }

    public CamelContext getCamelContext()
    {
        return cctx;
    }


}

//multitenant approach, switch from one database to another 
//based on BatchTenantContext resolution..
    public class BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

        static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.class);


        @Override
        public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
            String val = BatchTenantContext.getInstance().get();
            log.info("*** get tenant " + val);
            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

So, how to know how route fire? Note thaht the class above is singleton..I'm in a right way?
I use jpa whitin hibernate provider, configured using rhe multitenant configuration like this post: http://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html
The application work in spring-boot Runtime environment or with Tomcat app server.

Any ideas about all?

Thanks so much!

roby

I add this code:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({ MultiTenantAfSissProperties.class, JpaProperties.class })
    @ImportResource(locations = { "classpath:applicationContent.xml" })
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class MultiTenantJpaConfiguration {

        static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantJpaConfiguration.class);

        @Inject
        private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

        @Inject
        MultiTenantAFSISSProperties multiTenantAFSISSProperties; //lista dei datasources collegati ai tenant

        @Bean
        public Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceRetrieval(){
            Map<String, DataSource> result = new HashMap<>();
            for (DataSourceProperties dsProperties : this.multiTenantAFSISSProperties.getDataSources()) {
                DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .url(dsProperties.getUrl())
                    .username(dsProperties.getUsername())
                    .password(dsProperties.getPassword())
                    .driverClassName(dsProperties.getDriverClassName());
                result.put(dsProperties.getTenantId(), factory.build());
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider(){
            return new AfsissMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return
         */
        @Bean 
        public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver(){
            return new BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
        }

        /**
         *  
         * @param multiTenantConnectionProvider
         * @param currentTenantIdentifierResolver
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
            CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {

            Map<String, Object> hibernateProps = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            hibernateProps.putAll(this.jpaProperties.getProperties());

            Map<String,String> all = this.jpaProperties.getProperties();
            for ( Map.Entry<String, String> prop : all.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(" " + prop.getKey() + " = " + prop.getValue());
            }

            hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
            hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
            hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);

            // No dataSource is set to resulting entityManagerFactoryBean
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean result = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            result.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { AfFileEntity.class.getPackage().getName() }); 
            result.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
            result.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProps);

            return result;
        }

        /**
         * crea la factory per ricavare l'entity manager
         * @param entityManagerFactoryBean
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
            return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
        }

        /**
         * get transaction manager 
* @param entityManagerFactory
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
            HibernateTransactionManager result = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            result.setAutodetectDataSource(false);
            result.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
            return result;
        }



}
```

In applicationContent.xml:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.dao" transaction-manager-ref="txManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

The class BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl is called in currentTenantIdentifierResolver() method above by spring transaction manager every time i use entity manager and transaction manager in csvHanlder :

```
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyCsvHandler {

    @Inject
    AFMOVCrudRepository _entitymanagerMov; //it extends JpaRepository

    @Inject
    AFVINCCrudRepository _entityManagerVINC;//it extends JpaRepository


    @Inject
    AFFileCrudRepository _entityManagerAfFile;//it extends JpaRepository




    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCsvHandler.class);



//save csv data on the right table on the right tenant
    public void doHandleCsvData(List<List<String>> csvData) throws FileNotEvaluableException
    {
        //System.out.println("stampo..");
        boolean status = true;
            if (csvData.size() > 0){
            AfFileEntity afbean = new AfFileEntity();
            afbean.setNomeFile("test");
            afbean.setDataImport(new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            afbean.setTipoFile("M");
            afbean.setAfStatoFlusso("I");

            _entityManagerAfFile.save(afbean);

            long pkfile = afbean.getId();
            logger.info("pkfile: " + pkfile);

            int i = 1; 
            logger.info("file size:" + csvData.size());
            for (List<String> rows : csvData){

                //for (int j = 0; i < rows.size(); j++){
                if (rows.get(2).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(...)){ 
                    MovEntity mbean = new MovEntity();
                    setMovFields(mbean, rows);
                    mbean.setAfFileId(afbean);
                    logger.info(String.valueOf((i++)) +  " " + mbean);

                    _entitymanagerMov.save(mbean);
                }
                else if (rows.get(2).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(..) || rows.get(2).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(..) ) { 
                    VincEntity vincBean = new VincEntity();  
                    setVincFields(vincBean, rows);
                    vincBean.setAfFileId(afbean);

                    logger.info(String.valueOf((i++)) +  " " + vincBean);

                    _entityManagerVINC.save(vincBean);
                }   
                else {
                    status = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
             if (!status) throw new FileNotEvaluableException("error file format");
        }

    }

    private void setVincFields(VincEntity vincBean, List<String> rows) {
        vincBean.setXXX().. and others methods
    }

    private void setMovFields(MovEntity mbean, List<String> rows) {
        mbean.setStxxx() and other .. methods

    }
            return new
```

Comment: Are you expecting to get "currently executing route" using the synchronized get method in `BatchTenantContext`? That won't work. You are always getting `tenant_1` because that is how you have implemented get method. `CamelContext.getRoute("id")` returns the route if it exits. In your case both routes exist. If you invert the code, and check for `tenant_2` first, you will always get that. It does not return currently executing route.

Comment: @Gautam , yes i expecting to get the currently executing route but i have not figure out how to.. Someone can help me with some advice? Thanks

Comment: If you could explain your flow a bit better. What I understand here is that you have two directories 1 and 2 and based on when files arrive there, one of your routes get triggered. The route invokes `myCsvHandler` and there you are probably trying to insert data into one of the two tenants. How exactly is `BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl` used? Is the bean `myCsvHandler` calling methods on this class to determine current tenant? In your first route, add a message header as tenant_1 and in second route as tenant_2. Then in your bean `myCsvHandler` just use that from `Exchange`.

Comment: @Gautam I add code to my question for you. The application call to BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl  happen before the myCsvHanlder method call..The link posted by me use threadlocal to get the context because it's a web servlet application..but my route is not a rest or restlet call...so i have to keep a cache of context with other approach..but i'm not a Camel expert..

Comment: When do this `BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl` call happen in the route? Also what method of this class is being invoked when the route is being processed? Can't see that in your route.

Comment: Hold on, found it. Here is your option. Create a ThreadLocal variable in `BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl` called currentTenant. Then in your route, add a simple `process` step where you set the `currentTenant` value for the route. In your `BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl` get method, just check for the threadlocal value.

Comment: @Gautam..ok.. i checkout and try to write a processor, and set threadlocal ..do you have an example or something similar?

For now i ask your last question:
method resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() when i copy a file in directory 1 or 2 
stack trace preview:-> processExchange(..) in camel org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.class
-> org.apache.camel..Pipeline.class method process(..) -> ... -> MyCsvHandler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$xx.doHandleCSVData(List) line: not available-> org.springframework...class line 277-> SessioneFactoryImpl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153110/discussion-between-gautam-and-robyp7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this in your routes

```
from("direct:csvprocessor1").routeId("tenant2").process((Exchange e)-> {
                BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.tenant.set("tenant_1");
            })
        .from("file:src/main/resources/data/2?move=OUT&moveFailed=REFUSED")
        .unmarshal().csv()
        .to("bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData")
        .setBody(constant("OK 2"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/html"));
```

And in your `BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl` implement it as
public

```
class BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl {
    public static ThreadLocal<String> tenant = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.class);


    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String val = tenant.get();
        log.info("*** get tenant " + val);
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }       
}
```